# The Stack Exchange app on iOS not always allowed to open a link in Safari

Tags: bug, ios-app, hyperlinks

I opened the answer *https://stackoverflow.com/a/47591692/52277* in the iOS Stack Exchange app version 1.6.6.2.

The link in comment stackoverflow.com/questions/46019988/… [ServiceCollection returns null for IOptions even though GetSection is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019988/servicecollection-returns-null-for-ioptions-even-though-getsection-is-working), when touch and hold, has an option to open link in Safari, which is very convenient.

However link in the answer “as described in Integration test with IOptions<> in .NET Core”, when touch and hold, does not have an option to open link in Safari.

I created this question as a bug, because I do not see any reason to not have such option. However, if there was some intentional design consideration not to show Safari as an option, please consider it as a feature request.